# How can I get digits out of a Perl bignum?

Tags: perl, bignum

I have a really big number in Perl. I use "bignum". How can I extract single digits out of this big number. For example if I have a number like this and what to get the 3rd digit from the end:

> 1029384710985234058763045203948520945862986209845729034856
>
> -> 8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

bignums are transparently available, so this will work:

```
$digit = substr($bignum, -3, 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

The `bignum` package uses `Math::BigInt` under the hood for integers.

From the `Math::BigInt` man page:

```
$x->digit($n);        # return the nth digit, counting from right
```

Note that counting starts at 0 for the rightmost digit.